# Create an array from the output of whiptail command

Tags: linux, shell-script, array, whiptail

So, I am trying to use `whiptail` command to give users option to choose different things they want to install in their system.
I use the `whiptail --checklist` command as below:

```
name =$(whiptail --title "Tools to install" --checklist 20 78 4 \
"NTP" "NTP setup" OFF\
"Perl" "Perl install" OFF\
"Ruby" "Ruby install" OFF \
"Python" "Python install" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

Now, if my users choose Perl and python, this will output "Perl" and "Python".
What I am looking for is to be able to convert these outputs into an array because ultimately I need to loop through this array. I need to feed these outputs as inputs to next command I am using.

Any help or lead will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is the `readarray` section of the `bash` man page helpful?  https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: Says 404 not found for that link

Comment: It's an easy Google.

Comment: It could have helped but it looks like it needs output as strings but whiptail gives output as "string". so, instead of perl, output is "perl". It did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple case, you would do something like this:

```
CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "Tools to install" \
  --checklist "Choose something" 20 78 4 \
  "NTP" "NTP setup" OFF \
  "Perl" "Perl install" OFF \
  "Ruby" "Ruby install" OFF \
  "Python" "Python install" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )
```

However, because the values returned by `whiptail` are quoted, this won't work. For example, this script:

```
CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "Tools to install" \
  --checklist "Choose something" 20 78 4 \
  "NTP" "NTP setup" OFF \
  "Perl" "Perl install" OFF \
  "Ruby" "Ruby install" OFF \
  "Python" "Python install" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )

for choice in "${CHOICES[@]}"; do
    echo "choice: $choice"
done
```

Will output (if I choose Ruby and Python):

```
choice: "Ruby"
choice: "Python"
```

And if one of your values contains whitespace, it will fall apart. For example, if I modify the command line like this:

```
CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "Tools to install" \
  --checklist "Choose something" 20 78 4 \
  "NTP Setup" "NTP setup" OFF \
  "Perl install" "Perl install" OFF \
  "Ruby" "Ruby install" OFF \
  "Python Install" "Python install" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )

for choice in "${CHOICES[@]}"; do
    echo "choice: $choice"
done
```

We get:

```
choice: "NTP
choice: Setup"
choice: "Perl
choice: install"
```

You can add an `eval` to the mix to take care of both the above problems:

```
eval CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "Tools to install" \
  --checklist "Choose something" 20 78 4 \
  "NTP Setup" "NTP setup" OFF \
  "Perl install" "Perl install" OFF \
  "Ruby" "Ruby install" OFF \
  "Python Install" "Python install" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )

for choice in "${CHOICES[@]}"; do
    echo "choice: $choice"
done
```

Given the same selections as the previous example, this will output:

```
choice: NTP Setup
choice: Perl install
```

Comment: Perfect! very well explained and this takes care of my issue. Much appreciated!

Comment: If this answer helped out, consider checking the checkmark to the left of the question to mark it "answered".